# Contracting number of columns in a image in opencv?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, mat

I have written code to convert an image to two part in Matlab as below

```
img1=imge(1:M,1:0.55*N,:);
img2=imge(1:M,0.55*N:N,:);
```

here imge is my input image, I am trying to convert this code to opencv. I tried to use cv::Resize ,but that doesn't work. Can you please help me out?

Comment: note that MATLAB would issue the following warning: `Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index`, so perhaps you should use fix/round to make sure the index `0.55*N` is a whole number

Comment: Yahh, i  did this.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
int b = static_cast<int>(0.55*N);
cv::Mat img1 = img.rowRange(0,M).colRange(0,b);
cv::Mat img2 = img.rowRange(0,M).colRange(b,N);
```

[Note](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-rowrange) [that](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-colrange) this simply creates a matrix header, the underlying data of the new matrix is shared with the original matrix.